# Self publish a Chrome extension with one-click install

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, publish

The Chrome Web Store installs extensions with one click.  From an extension's Chrome Web Store page, you simply click the INSTALL button and are not required to confirm or take any additional actions.  Is it possible to replicate this exact experience outside of the Chrome Web Store?

I know you can link to the Web Store page, but that's two clicks.  Or you can link directly to the extension packages, but that requires a second confirmation click for install.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you host your own extensions you can link on it

```
<a href="your_extenison_or_app_or_theme.crx">Install</a>
```

You have to pack it with Chrome new page tab's extension packer. This is the nearest you can get.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer true:

http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769&p=crx_warning

There are instructions there now, how to help people install the extension that is not hosted by google, but pretty much, you have to pay the fee to google, and then get it in the web store in order to make updates, and generally be a good developer.